# How to allow space in input form

Tags: php, input, validation

I am trying to build site with custom script. I have problem with allowing space in Name input field. If i include space, it will give error but if input slash or underscore, it accepts.

my name  - i am getting not allowed error 
my_name  - i am getting success message.

code

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9a-zA-Z\xe0-\xef\x80-\xbf._-]+$/i',$nickname)) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **\s** for space to your regex.

I have try this :

```
[0-9a-zA-Z\xe0-\xef\x80-\xbf._-]+\s*
```

For debugging regex may be you can use [this tools](http://www.rubular.com/).